# How can I run Bugzilla on Windows with Strawberry Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, bugzilla

I've been at it for 3 days now, and run into, usually, a Storage.pm problem with the "Binary image v18.86 being greater than 2.7".

I've tried different Bugzilla's: 3.0.8, 3.2.4, 3.4rc1.

Next I'll be trying different Perl's, (using 5.10.0.4 portable right now),

I don't want to go to an older version of MySQL (5.1.36-community), so next I'll try PostgreSQL 8.4.

I'll update as I go. I wanted to ask here, since these are some common platforms, and perhaps someone has it working.

P.S.: Windows XP, Abyss Web Server X1 (though I can't even run perl check-setup.pl yet)

**UPDATE:** A [chronicle](http://plzsendtehcodez.blogspot.com/2009/07/perl-perl-perl.html) of my (so far) fruitless journey.

Answer (score 1):

not quite a direct answer to your question, but have you considered running debian or ubuntu or some other linux distro inside Virtual Box on your XP machine?

software like bugzilla and perl and mysql and postgresql will always run better on their "native" unix-like type environment than on windows.

Comment: I have, and that might be the next step. I think the very next step will be to try ActiveState after all, and then off to Linux. But, I'd love to be able to deploy to Windows easily.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully installed bugzilla-3.2.4 on Windows XP, IIS 6.0, MySQL 5.1.36 and ActivePerl-5.10. The bugzilla site recommends using Active Perl.

Anyway what is the exact error you and get and in what scenario its coming?

Comment: Follow the link where I "chronicle" what has happened. I will be using ActivePerl next, but it's good to hear a success story here.

Comment: But, the exact error: `Use of uninitialized value $version in int at Bugzilla/DB/Schema.pm line 2426.
Storable binary image v18.86 more recent than I am (v2.7) at ..\..\lib\Storable.
pm (autosplit into ..\..\lib\ale\thaw.al) line 415, at Bugzilla/DB/Schema.pm lin
e 2426`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Strawberry Perl, but installing with ppm. ppm is used by Strawberry too, but primary instrument for installing modules is CPAN shell. It seems that you broke Storable module. You will need to reinstall Strawberry and start with installing Bundle::Bugzilla. Bundle::Bugzilla was not updated for a long time, but it is a good start.

Another way is to use ActivePerl.